# How does this Python code works?

Tags: python

I came across this piece of code -

```
b = [0, 1, 2, 3]
for b[-1] in b:
    print(b[-1])
```

The output for the code is

```
0 1 2 2
```

What is the flow of the snippet?

Comment: Try http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html to visualize execution.

Comment: @strippenzieher: Interesting link. Or simply : `print(b)` at each iteration.

Comment: @EricDuminil  its bit tricky , why its replacing `b[-1]`  each time, we have not performing assignment operation here. can anyone elaborate?

Comment: @Sanket: See the duplicate question. `for x in b` calls an assignment to `x`, whatever `x` is.

Comment: We *are* performing assignment, however, we are assigning to `b[-1]`. Just the same as if we do `for x in range(3):`, `x` will be assigned `x = 0; x = 1; x = 2`, here, `b[-1] = 0; b[-1] = 1;  b[-1] = 2` , then we get to the last iteration, which assigns the last value, which the previous iteration has assigned to `b[-1] = 2`

Comment: @EricDuminil Thanks  understood